# multiple value from mysql to reportlab

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, reportlab

i have an issue that i can't show my second record in mysql table. The report just showing 1 record in a row and the second one isn't show on pdf file. i'm using reportlab for report generator on python 2.7

this is my code that i can' fix yet :

```
def nilaisql():
  rpt = raw_input("input NPM : ")
  sql = "select nama, tanggal, jamMasuk from t_"+rpt
  curs.execute(sql)
  result = curs.fetchall()
  for row in result:
      c = canvas.Canvas("Sampelone.pdf")
      c.drawString(250, 700, str(row[0]))
      c.save()
  os.system("Sampelone.pdf")
```

this is my record on mysql. I want to show the second row record but the pdf just showing the first row record

[it should showing the second row record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjhEi.jpg)

[and this is the result on my pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I2gZ.png)

i'm getiing stuck in here and if you know something i'm really grateful that you can share the solution in here

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in result:
  c = canvas.Canvas("Sampelone.pdf")
  c.drawString(250, 700, str(row[0]))
  c.save()
```

what your code snippet is doing is, creating a new file and writing the content of your variable `row` into the pdf file and `c.save` saves it. In the next iteration, this same file is recreated which is blank and the original file is overwritten by this blank file and the content of `row` is printed that is why you will always see only first row record in it.

This should work fine. Increment or Decrement the value of y according to your use and document height.

```
c = canvas.Canvas("Sampelone.pdf") #creates a pdf
for row in result:   
  c.drawString(250, y, str(row[0])) #writes data at given co-ordinates
c.save() #saves the pdf
```

This way you can see all row records in the pdf.
 
**But this practice is not considered good, you should always put your data in flowable like this. .**

```
from reportlab.lib import styles
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph


def nilaisql():
    pdfname = 'mydoc.pdf'
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
        pdfname
    )
    style = styles["Normal"]
    story = []


    rpt = raw_input("input NPM : ")
    sql = "select nama, tanggal, jamMasuk from t_" + rpt
    curs.execute(sql)
    result = curs.fetchall()

    for row in result:
        story.append(Paragraph(row, style))

    doc.build(
        story
    )

    os.system("Sampelone.pdf")
```

Read more about flowables in [reportlab-userguide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf)